# advanced-ish C programming in Windows (pthreads, signals and semaphores, oh my!)

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, operating-system, posix

I'm in my third year studying computer science, so I should probably actually know the answer to this question already, but nonetheless, I don't. Anyway, I'm taking the OS course for my degree currently and we've been been covering a lot of new programming concepts like signals, semaphores, and threads in C. Unfortunately, my prof is covering all of these in a Linux/OS X perspective. What this means for me, being on a 64-bit windows machine, is that things like installing an alarm signal, or using semaphores and pthreads won't compile or run on my machine (as far as I can tell).

Anyway, currently I have just been doing my assignments in a VM running Linux, which has worked well so far, but I much prefer the Windows environment for coding.

So, after that heavy winded introduction, my question is, as you might have already guessed, is there a way to code with all these features (alarm signals, semaphores, pthreads, etc.) and be able to compile and test them in Windows? I'm fully aware that the Windows OS does not support the alarm signal and has limited POSIX capability, but I've heard rumors tossed around about cygwin (which I did try to get to work, but not very hard :P) and micro Linux kernels that you can run in the background to use these features.

Anyway, if anyone can give me maybe a list of options they would recommend (preferably not stick with your VM, even though I'm thinking that might be my best option) and maybe some tips, pros, cons, maybe a setup guide, or really any non-empty subset of these options I would really appreciate it. Also, before you ask, we have to use C and the above mentioned programming features in our assignments, so there's no switch to Java or code in win32 option unfortunately :(

Thanks in advance to anyone who can lend some words of wisdom :)

Comment: I think a Raspberry Pi system costs around 60 Euro and is capable of running Linux. You could program it remotely using e.g. SSH or Cygwin's X server. And it's a nice toy!

Comment: Another option that is similar to a VM but in my opinion last cumbersome is to use Amazon Web Services.  If your assignments aren't computationally expensive you can run them for free on a micro instance on AWS.  A small learning curve there to get it going but once there it's a great way to access linux machines from windows when you need them without putting extra strain on your machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) - a Windows port of the GNU toolchain - and [Pthreads-win32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/), a POSIX wrapper of the Windows threading API.

I'm using these via the `mingw64-x86_64` Cygwin cross-compiler packages (which currently provide the somewhat dated gcc 4.5.3) instead of directly for two reasons: First, I need other stuff from the GNU toolbox, and second because of the package manager.

I'm not sure to what degree Pthreads-win32 complies to POSIX, but I can confirm that LLVM and Clang both compile with this setup.

Answer (score 3):

The basic principles are all there in Windows but done differently. And I recommend that, if you're going to program for Windows, you do this in the Windows API rather than through an emulation layer like Cygwin. If anything at all you'll quickly learn that different operating systems take a different approach to signalling and process handling.

First thing to be aware of is that threads are much more lightweight in Windows while processes are significantly more heavyweight. With that in mind Windows programs operate most efficiently when using threads. There is the concept of the [CriticalSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that you should become very familiar with. And the [Semaphore Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Keep reading the API and you'll find a wealth of information about these topics - the Microsoft documentation is actually rather good. A key thing to understand about the Windows API is that you almost always have to "create/get" a new object (and obtain a handle) before you can use it. And Windows doesn't like programs having too many handles.

Personally I like the POSIX API and have a love for Linux. But I do appreciate that if you want to do things properly in Windows you should be using the Windows OS API - they have thought about this carefully even though the results and methods may be somewhat different.

PS Windows doesn't have the "alarm". It is perhaps the single most prohibitive barrier to simply porting Unix/Linux utilities to Windows. (That and the fact that Windows processes have to "bootstrap" Internet/socket support before using it whereas Linux processes are good to go).

Comment: Actually, I'm aware of the capabilities of the Windows API, but as this is for school, I need to use what the prof uses. This means that I am required to use the POSIX API for all signals, semaphores and threads and my submissions for assignments should run properly when run on a Linux (actually Unix) machine. So, basically the Windows API is not an option for me. So any other options for running these POSIX features in Windows are much appreciated :)

Comment: Personally my hands-down approach is [Colinux](http://www.colinux.org/) which runs a Linux VM as a Windows process (so you can run Windows while you also run Linux inside Windows). However you already have a VM. And CoLinux may have trouble with a 64-bit host operating system. These days all the kids are using something else.. maybe VirtualBox? I don't remember.